# docker can't find cypress install when binding windows folder with docker image

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, docker, cypress

I have an issue with my docker and cypress from Windows machine.

I am using `git bash` to run my `e2e.sh` script. All is happening on windows level.
My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copy .e2e.npmrc file to .npmrc
cp .e2e.npmrc .npmrc

if [[ $1 == "clear" ]]; then
    # Build Docker image with no cache
    echo "Building Docker image..."
    docker build -t front-e2e .

    # Stop and remove any existing container with the same name
    echo "Stopping and removing existing container..."
    docker stop front-e2e
    docker rm front-e2e

    # Set NPM_TOKEN environment variable
    if [[ -z "${NPM_TOKEN}" ]]; then
        export NPM_TOKEN=$(cat ~/.npmrc | grep -o '_authToken=.*' | head -1 | sed 
    's/_authToken=//g')
    fi

    # Run Docker container with bind mount and environment variable
    echo "Running Docker container..."
    docker run -d --name front-e2e -e NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} --mount 
    type=bind,source="C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\projects\front-mobile-web",target=/front- 
    mobile-web,consistency=full -v /front-mobile-web/node_modules -t front-e2e

    # Install dependencies and list files in /front-mobile-web directory
    echo "Installing dependencies..."
    docker exec front-e2e yarn install -w /front-mobile-web


fi

# Run e2e tests
echo "Running e2e tests..."
docker exec front-e2e yarn nx run export-app-e2e:e2e -w "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\projects\front-mobile-web"

# Remove .npmrc file
rm .npmrc
```

So here

```
docker run -d --name front-e2e -e NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} --mount 
type=bind,source="C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\projects\front-mobile-web",target=/front- 
mobile-web,consistency=full -v /front-mobile-web/node_modules -t front-e2e
```

I am binding my windows folder.
In `Docker` file i have this:

```
FROM node:18

RUN apt update
RUN apt install xvfb libgconf-2-4 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnss3-dev libxss-dev libasound2 -y

RUN useradd -d /home/air -m -s /bin/bash air
RUN mkdir -p /front-mobile-web ; chown -R air:air /front-mobile-web
RUN mkdir -p /front-mobile-web/node_modules ; chown -R air:air /front-mobile-web/node_modules

VOLUME ["/front-mobile-web"]
USER air
WORKDIR /front-mobile-web
```

Thanks to that i can sart my `e2e.sh` script and it is almost working. It is creating container stopping deleting and even binding my folder, but I have two issues.
One is during `Linking dependencies`:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EIO: i/o error, unlink '/front-mobile-web/node_modules/@parcel/watcher/prebuilds/win32-x64/node.napi.glibc.node'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/front-mobile-web/yarn-error.log".
```

and second is when my e2e test is running:

```
No version of Cypress is installed in: /home/air/.cache/Cypress/12.9.0/Cypress

Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install

----------

Cypress executable not found at: /home/air/.cache/Cypress/12.9.0/Cypress/Cypress

----------

Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.6)
Cypress Version: 12.9.0
```

In my `node_modules` I do have cypress installed and i can run cypress tests localy from electron with no issues

Getting to this point took me like whole week and in general this is only issue that I have right now with this